# Opticon USB driver/SDK for windows 10

Tags: android, google-chrome, sdk, usb, driver

Does anyone know where to find the sdk/usb driver for an Opticon H27? I wan't to enable remote debugging on the device, but I can not find any suitable USB driver.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but if you're still looking for the Android USB drivers for Opticon H27, it is indicated in their user manual [here](http://www.opticonusa.com/modx/downloads/documents/user_manual/Opticon%20H-27%20Enterprise%20Administrator%20User%20Guide.pdf)
at page 6.

The drivers are in the device itself or you could download from Google.

Here is what the manual says:

**From H-27**

1. Connect H-27 via USB to the PC
2. Enable UMS on H-27. (There's this notification that will be shown in notification bar that will say something like 'Connected as a media device/storage/.. Touch for other USB options.' Tap it and select USB Mass Storage device (UMS))
3. An AutoPlay CDROM drive will be mounted. Either

   a. Select Run autorun.cmd to automatically install 64-bit or 32-bit ADB/Fastboot USB drivers

   b. Or, manually install 64-bit or 32-bit ADB/Fastboot USB drivers

   For 64-bit systems use CDROM drive>:\Driver\Install_x64\adb_driver_x64.exe

   For 32-bit systems use CDROM drive>:\Driver\Install_x86\adb_driver.exe

In my case, the drivers in the device would not install in Windows 10. It fails to install but I noticed afterwards that my IDE (Eclipse) could now detect the device and I can now debug.

The manual also mentioned the it has issues installing in Windows 8.1 (I suppose it also includes Windows 10). If it doesn't work, you may try this instead:

**From Google**

1. Download this zip-file https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/latest_usb_driver_windows.zip and unzip
2. Unzip to a known location
3. Enable USB debugging on H-27 and connect it via USB to your PC
4. Open Device Manager
5. In Device Manager right click H-27 and chose “Update driver...”
6. Select “Browse my computer for driver software”
7. Select “Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer”
8. Chose the row “Show all devices” and click “Next”
9. Select “Have disk...”
10. “Browse...” to the folder location of the unzipped ADB driver from Google and click “Open” and then “OK”
11. Click “Next”, choose “Android ADB Interface” and then click “Yes” in the dialog showing a warning message
12. Click ”Install” in the dialog box asking if you trust Google Inc
    13.Verify H-27 is now identified as an Android device in the Device Manager

Hope it helps.